# Как отминусовать j

Tags: python, list, index

```
list=[1,2,2,2,3,3]
for j in range(0,4):
    print(j)
    if list[j]==list[j+1]:
        list.pop(j)
        # j=j-1
print(list)
```

Нужно чтобы значение j не менялось в случае, если list[j]==list[j+1] так как после удаления элемента из списка все элементы смещаются и индексы соответственно тоже. Подскажите, как это реализовать

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста конечную цель. Правильно я понимаю, что из исходного списка нужно удалить повторяющиеся значения?

Comment: типичный случай [проблемы XY](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_XY_(%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0))

Comment: Если уж вы пишете такие алгоритмы вручную - выкиньте цикл for и используйте while.

Answer (score 3):

### 1

От каждой группы одинаковых элементов нужно оставить одного представителя - [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools


list_1 = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
list_2 = [k for k, _ in itertools.groupby(list_1)]
print(list_2)
```

> ```
> [1, 2, 3]
> ```

### 2

Если править именно ваш код, то надо заменить цикл с `for` на `while`. Так можно лучше контролировать индексы. Верхняя граница цикла меняется когда удаляется элемент:

```
list_ = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
j = 0
while j < len(list_) - 1:
    print(j)
    if list_[j] == list_[j + 1]:
        list_.pop(j)
    else:
        j += 1
print(list_)
```

Я бы не советовал так делать. В некоторых ситуациях этот код работает медленнее чем возможно. Попробуйте его на миллионе единиц, чтобы понять  о чем речь.

### 3

Первый способ прост, но использует библиотеку. Кроме того он копирует список, что может быть проблемой если размер списка сопоставим с размером памяти. Второй способ экономит память, но работает очень долго на длинных списках с большим числом повторяющихся элементов. Есть алгоритм, который работает быстро и не требует дополнительной памяти.

Индекс `i` пробегает весь список без первого элемента. `j` отстаёт от него каждый раз когда соседние элементы равны. Различные элементы накапливаются в начале списка. Когда цикл окончен `j` указывает на хвост списка с "мусором". Этот хвост отрезается:

```
list_ = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
j = 1
for i in range(1, len(list_)):
    if list_[i - 1] != list_[i]:
        list_[j] = list_[i]
        j += 1
del list_[j:]
print(list_)
```

### 4

Самый первый способ можно доработать так чтобы он не требовал дополнительной памяти:

```
import itertools


list_ = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
list_[:] = (k for k, _ in itertools.groupby(list_))
print(list_)
```

### 5

Вариант без дополнительной памяти, библиотек и индексов:

```
def uniqs(seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    try:
        prev = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    yield prev
    for v in it:
        if v != prev:
            yield v
            prev = v


list_ = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
list_[:] = uniqs(list_)
print(list_)
```

**P.S.** Последние три варианта реализуют один и тот же алгоритм различными средствами.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Проще это сделать вообще другим способом - с помощью спискового сокращения, чем мучиться с индексами и изменяющимся при итерировании списком:

```py
lst=[1,2,2,2,3,3]
lst = [a for a,b in zip(lst, lst[1:] + [None]) if a != b]
print(lst)
```

Вывод:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy 3 не попадёт без `None` )  Да, я помню был какой-то рецепт ещё

Comment: Вы правы, я не увидел этого. Клиническая картина представляется удручающей.

Answer (score 0):

Или одной строкой:

```
lst = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]    
lst = list(set(lst)) # [1, 2, 3]
```

P.S.  Использовать зарезервированное Python-ом ключевое слово list не очень хорошая идея.

Comment: Ваш способ мощнее чем алгоритм ТС. Его код каждую группу подряд идущих элементов сокращает до одного элемента. Ваш склеивает все группы вместе.